# Unable to import Django models in python script

Tags: django, django-models

My code is here.
I have tried different approach from stackoverflow and non of them worked.

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

sys.path.append('/var/www/iaas/horizon')
sys.path.append('/var/www/iaas/horizon/openstack_dashboard')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'openstack_dashboard.settings'

from bill.models import MonthlyBills
from django.contrib.auth import models
```

If I run python daemonize.py, here is the error message I get.
I am confused because I have already included my django project path in my sys.path

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name connection
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create a python-daemon, I need to have an access in my django models.

I hope someone who could point me where I am mistaking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` **before** you import `settings`.

The process of importing `django.conf.settings` will look to see if the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable is set before determining white settings to load.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/iaas/horizon')
sys.path.append('/var/www/iaas/horizon/openstack_dashboard')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'openstack_dashboard.settings'

from django.conf import settings
```

Comment: Thanks Austin for answering, I did what you have suggested but the issue still there. I am can't still import any django models in my script, the error message is the same. ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name auth

Comment: What I need to do is to have access in my django models for my python-daemon script

Comment: Is your script running inside the same environment as the django instance?

Comment: My script is located in my django project. But I am running the script  separately. I use "python /var/www/iaas/horizon/collector/daemon.py run" to run the daemon script

Comment: @DjangoBot Put a `print sys.path` before importing Django settings to verify that your path is correct.  This error could also occur if more than one directory named `openstack_dashboard` is on your sys.path, but one of the directories doesn't contain the `settings.py` file.  Also check that there is an `__init__.py` in your `openstack_dashboard` directory.

Comment: I know now whats wrong! I have multiple folders in my system that has a subfolder openstack_dashboard, the PYTHONPATH got confused. What I did is I trace all of them and  remove it then this code worked: sys.path.append("/var/www/cloudloon/horizon")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "openstack_dashboard.settings"
from openstack_dashboard import settings